Cursor jumping around when using MudTextField together with PatternMask or RegexMask
Cursor Jumping issue in Blazor server app when I use mask in MudTextField. I have used debounceinterval too but not working. It is working fine in my local but when Deployed to server i am seeing this caret jumping issue.
When I enter a phone number I should not see my caret jumping in MudTextField.

Masking doesn't work correctly in server mode due to the constant signalR communication required, which comes with some latency. A JavaScript implementation is required https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/8186#issuecomment-1949353592
